# Leverage counting by hatvalues vs counting by myself

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have following question : 
Let's say that I'm dealing with this simple model :

```
x=rnorm(10)
z=runif(10)
y=c()
y=x-z
model=lm(y~x)
```

And I want to count leverages, by myself and by hatvalues so :

```
X=model.matrix(model)
H = X %*% solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% t(X)
diag(H)   #leverages counted by myself
hatvalues(model)   #leverages counted by implemented function
diag(H)==hatvalues(model)
```

And I have a problem with the very last line, because values of vectors diag(H) and hatvalues(model) are almost equal... but not equal.

I define vector which will count differences between them to get :

```
> p=c()
> for (i in 1:10){
+   p[i]=abs(diag(H)[i]-hatvalues(model)[i])
+ }
> p
 [1] 2.775558e-17 1.387779e-17 5.551115e-17 0.000000e+00 1.665335e-16
 [6] 0.000000e+00 2.775558e-17 2.775558e-17 1.387779e-17 2.775558e-17
```

So the differences are very small, but what's the reason of their existence ?